# Stop audio 'Download' option covering the player

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

I have an `audio` element but when I click the 3 dots icon to download it covers the whole player:

[image]

Is there any way to put it at the bottom like a Tooltip? Or perhaps to make it a separate download button? If it is please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the default `audio` control. The UI for it is handled by the browser at a lower level than JS has access to.

You have two alternatives. One is to use your own audio player, or to download an existing one.

The other is to remove the 'Download' link using `controlslist="nodownload"`. Then you can add your own download button to your site wherever it's required.

Comment: Thanks @Rory how can I exactly link my Button to make audio download?

Comment: `<a href="url_to_your_audio.mp3" download>Download audio here</a>`